# How to get the "The Sea is a cruel mistress" achievement?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

The achievement "The Sea is a cruel mistress" is simply described as "Drown". I guess I have to get into water, but I don't see how.

I can't walk into it, I can't be moved by a monster, and teleporting always make you land on solid ground. How am I supposed to drown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do it is to get the vampirism skill tree. The fifth skill in that tree, *Transylvation*, allows you to turn into a batty, which can fly over the water. You can then wait until the spell ends, and you'll fall into the water, dying instantly.

Example:

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you don't have the ability to run out of time and fall as listed before or directly teleport in water, you could use the daggers' 1'st skill "Liechtenauer's Switcheroo" to "Swap" with an enemy when they are on the border of water. This causes you to flank into the water and instantly drown. I didn't realize what happened the first time I did this and it had to happen a second time to notice this.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally set this post as "Community Wiki" (there's a checkbox) which a) means that you don't get any reputation for it, and b) is a shame, because it's a good answer and you deserve the rep for it. In general, *very, very few* answers should be Community Wiki.